# GPS functionality on tum_simulator package

Tags: ros, gps, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like ask anybody who probably have integrated the GPS capability on tum_simulator package. What I am aware of is that I need to add the GPS plugin but then, a few steps more perhaps needed in order to publish the GPS topic.

Could you please share your experience like what are the steps required, or better still patch or needed related files.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191282/gps-functionality-on-tum_simulator-package/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tum_simulator package already has a gps plugin (at least in the [master branch](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator/blob/master/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/urdf/quadrotor_sensors.urdf.xacro#L53), which is for Hydro). It publishes a sensor_msgs::NavSatFix in the /fix topic.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1